# jQuery : Performing task based on multiple events with or condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am implementing search functionality  and an ajax request is sent upon textbox change event of a text field. This is working fine but now i have to add a panel of search boxes as well to the search criteria , I am getting the checkboxes values on change as below :

```
$('.child_filter input:checkbox').change(function() {
            var type=  $(this).attr("data-type");
            var val=$(this).val();
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                if(type=='subject'){
                    subjects.push($(this).val());
                }
                else if(type=='topic'){
                    topics.push($(this).val());
                }
                else if(type=='user'){
                    users.push($(this).val());
                }

            }
            var new_subjects = subjects.join().replace(/,/g, "|");
            var new_topics = topics.join().replace(/,/g, "|");
            var new_users = users.join().replace(/,/g, "|");

            localStorage.setItem("global_search_users",new_users);
            localStorage.setItem("global_search_topics",new_topics);
            localStorage.setItem("global_search_subjects",new_subjects);

        });

})
```

*Update :*

Now what happens is checkboxes values are taken from the `localStorage` and sent to controller and search is only  performed on textfield change event

Code for text field change event with ajax request :

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchbox', function(){
           var s_string =$(this).val();
                    console.log('tabs_content');
                    var users = localStorage.getItem('global_search_users');
                    var topics = localStorage.getItem('global_search_topics');
                    var subjects = localStorage.getItem('global_search_subjects');
                    var tabs_content = custom_base_url+'admin/books/create';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data:  {'search_string_in':s_string,'users':users,'topics':topics,'subjects':subjects},  
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Based on selection of any checkbox I perform some action on selected checkboxes before sending it to search query, Same thing I am doing with text field.

can someone guide me how can I manage both events in one function with the detection as well like on which element did this change happen

currently search is performed in 2 separate functions, I check on change event for text field and checkboxes, what I want is that there is one function that detects which element is changed (checkbox or text field) and in if else block performs their relevant actions and result is embedded to Dom

Comment: Put the common logic in a function within scope of both event handlers, and then call it from within those event handlers. Have that function read the values from `localStorage` and then make the AJAX request to retrieve the entities and update the DOM. Also, I would strongly suggest using a single object for the search criteria instead of multiple separate arrays. If you require a working example of how to do the above, please edit the question to include your other event handler for the text fields

Comment: I have updated the code pls check ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would implement your code above:

```
$.fn.values = function () {
    return this.map(function () { return this.value; }).toArray();
}

function updateSearch() {
    $.post(custom_base_url + 'admin/books/create', {
        search_string_in: $('#searchbox').val(),
        users: $('.child_filter :checkbox[data-type=users]:checked').values().join('|'),
        topics: $('.child_filter :checkbox[data-type=topic]:checked').values().join('|'),
        subjects: $('.child_filter :checkbox[data-type=subject]:checked').values().join('|')
    }).done(function (data) {
        // now do something with the response data
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#searchbox', updateSearch);
$(document).on('click', '.child_filter :checkbox', updateSearch);
```

Storing anything in `localStorage` seems unnecessary, so I removed that part. Using live values when you do the Ajax request is fine. Although...

- you probably don't want to POST to `'admin/books/create'` on keyup in the search box, but rather want to use GET on a different endpoint.
- you might want to use CSS classes instead of `data-type="..."`, this would make elements much easier to select.

Generally, for the purpose of a search field I would not recommend sending an Ajax request on *every* keyup event, this will create unnecessary request spam on the server, and it will mess with your user interface since there will be an update for ever key the user has pressed, even if they type very quickly. [Debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the event handler, so it only executes X milliseconds after the user has stopped typing:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchbox', debounce(updateSearch, 250));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the event is on text field , how shall we request a search result based on checkbox change as  i mentioned in question i want to  fetch a new result set on change of textfield or chcekbox

Comment: @Sikander Ah, you can wire up the same event handler to different events. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, let me try this

Comment: One more thing can i return values  to a variable on change event from done function instead of appending it ?

Comment: @Sikander No, you can't return values from asynchronous functions. But you can either do whatever work needs to be done inside the `.done()` function, or write another top-level function that does that work, and call it from within the `.done()` function.

Comment: okay , will need to write another function insdie done function in that case , Thanks bro